# как разделить строку в питоне на отдельные символы и записать в список(пробелов между символами нет)

Tags: python

как разделить строку в питоне на отдельные символы и записать в список(пробелов между символами нет)

Comment: Вы сами не пытались решить такую простейшую задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Легко!

```
s = 'hello'
a = list(s)
```